# Как сделать редирект на refresh-token при AuthenticationFailed на asp.net core web api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, аутентификация, jwt

Уже настроена аутентификация на проекте `asp.net core web api`. Нужно сделать, что бы при истечении срока жизни `access token` делался redirect на `refresh-token` endpoint, но не могу понять как его вообще сделать. Вот часть конфигурации аутентификации:

```
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    string securityKey = builder.Configuration.GetSection("JwtOptions:SecurityKey").Value;
    byte[] byteKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(securityKey);

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(byteKey)
    };

    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            context.Token = context.Request.Cookies["access-token"];
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("https://localhost:8876/api/v1.0/authentication/refresh-token");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnChallenge = context => // Это не нужно, но так тоже не работает
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("https://localhost:8876/api/v1.0/authentication/refresh-token");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```

Когда получаю `HttpStatusCode401`, срабатывает событие `OnAuthenticationFailed`, но `context.Response.Redirect()` ничего не делает (Это не странно, он возвращает `void`). Тут вопрос, а как тогда сделать редирект на другой эндпоинт, что бы получить новый `access token` перед тем, как вернётся `HttpStatusCode401` и вернуть **нормальный** `StatusCode`?